# ElasticSearch Query: Can't get all aggregated results

Tags: elasticsearch, key, sharding, bucket

In ElasticSearch, I have 5 shards, and I have documents like this in each shards.
[{userId:XX, name:YYY, bookId:"123abc" },....]

I group by "bookId" and try to get all books that have been borrowed by more than one user:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "group_by_bookId": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "bookId.keyword",
            "size": 10000
        },
        "aggs": {
            "having_several": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "the_doc_count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": "params.the_doc_count > 1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this query do return say 500 buckets, which less than 10000, that means the query does return all documents it has. But when I search one field "bookId" = "123abc",there are 5 documents in return, but key="123abc" doesn't show in that return buckets "key" list, and I know that we have 5 documents that "bookId" = "123abc" located in each shard(Each shard only has one document that "bookId" = "123abc"). "aggs" works only on each shard, and combinates all returns from each shard, each shard only have one document for "bookId"="123abc", so it doesn't return that doucment in each shard.

So my question is any solution(elasticsearch query) for finding all documents that have duplicated value, no matter which shard those documents located.

Answer (score 0):

I think that min_doc_count could help you.
The query will look like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_bookId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bookId.keyword",
        "size": 10000,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the Elasticsearch documentation, min_doc_count is supposed to sort the results after the marge phase:

> The min_doc_count criterion is only applied after merging local terms
> statistics of all shards.

If this won't work, you can try to play with shard_size parameter in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesn't work, and min_doc_count default value is 1.